# how do i access files in directory from another directory (linux)

Tags: linux

im trying to change permissions on a txt file founded in directory X 
While im in the directory Y

```
  kosay_sabbah@DESKTOP-87R0T4M:~/Kosay/grp2$ chmod 777 3.txt

  chmod: cannot access '3.txt': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use absolute or relative file path. For example you have `file1.txt` in directory `/directory1/` - absolute file path is `/directory1/file1.txt`. If your current path is `/directory2/`, you can run `chmod` for file1.txt in two ways:

1. Using relative path - `chmod ../directory1/file1.txt`
2. Using absolute path - `chmod /directory1/file1.txt`